# Pass list object between Activity and Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a list object, it contains information about 1 photo in 1 album.

```
@Parcelize
data class MediaFileModel(
    var uri: Uri,
    var name: String,
    var bucketId: Long = 0,
    var bucketName: String = "",
    var duration: String = "",
    var length: Double = 0.0,
    var albumId: Long = 0,
    var songAlbum: String = "",
    var pathFile: String = "",
    var id: Long = 0
) : Parcelable
```

How to transfer it from one Activity to another as optimally as possible? Pass it through Parcelable or create a Singleton class to store it or is there a better way? Thank

When consulting more from ChatGPT, I see that it is also possible to use json to transmit data, but what is the performance between these 3 ways and the possibility of memory leaks?

Comment: Please don't use images of text.

Comment: Have you tried both already?

Comment: I've tried both, but I'm not sure which is the most optimal and safest way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code. Always put the code into the question and format it with the formatting tools into code. It is not allowed to post screenshots of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: Thank you, however I already know how to transmit but want to ask the most optimal way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parcelable should be the best practice to pass small amounts of data efficiently. Here is why:

- Parcelable is an interface that allows you to serialize and deserialize objects for efficient and high-performance passing of data between components, such as activities, services, and fragments.
- In kotlin, there is @Parcelize annotation to implement Parcelable easily.
- In API level 33, Google added new method [getParcelableArrayListExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20T%3E)) in `Intent` to use Parcelable without needing to cast class type. Yeah, we know that they **deprecated** so much classes and methods if needed but not this one right?

There is also androidx support for Parcelable in `IntentCompat` class.

```kotlin
IntentCompat.getParcelableArrayListExtra(intent, name, class)
IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(intent, name, class)
```

- Parcelable is faster than alternatives like Serializable because it uses a lower-level approach and is designed and optimized for Android's IPC (Inter-Process Communication) system.

Comment: Like my example, if the list object has a size of thousands or tens of thousands, will this affect performance?

Comment: Parcelable should be used for small data (a few kilobytes or less) to ensure optimal performance.
Data size means total bytes, not list count. Large data should be stored in persistence storage like Room database to avoid performance issues. Parcelable size impacts performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this for my project